# Android: Add a single page title strip bar

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity and I want to put a simple title strip like the picture below(Select a category) but I can't find anything on how to do a simple one. Only title strips for tabs. Is anyone know how to implement this? Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be your best solution - http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android.

Check the custom adapter in the link. You could also have multiple headers too, but if you only want one, then you can just have the code like below

```
package com.javatechig;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SectionListView extends ListActivity {

    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Select A Category"); // <--- here

        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {

            mAdapter.addItem("Item: " + i);

        }

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And I like more from the one that I showed. Thanks :D